# how to send variable on video event on amp page

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics

Assuming I have a couple of `<amp-video>` elements and I want to send player events of trigger `video-play` [https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/amp-video-analytics.md] and I want to send the data-vars as query param for the in house analytics.

the click event is sent as expected with all query params filled.
However, the video-view event is sent with all query params except for the video_id.

any suggestions?

for example:
`

```
<amp-video class="myVideo" autoplay loop width="640" height="360" layout="responsive" data-vars-video-id="123456" poster="...">
      <source src="....mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <div fallback>
        <amp-img src="...jpg" width="16" height="9" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
      </div>
    </amp-video>
...
<amp-analytics>
    <script type="application/json">
      {
        "requests": {
          "event":  "https://counter.exmple.io/_track?event=${eventType}&url=${canonicalUrl}&user=CLIENT_ID(ampCid)&video_id=${videoId}"
        },
        "triggers": {
          "minVideoPlay": {
            "on": "video-play",
            "selector": ".myVideo",
            "request": "event",
            "vars": {
              "eventType": "video-view"
            }
          },
          "minClick": {
            "on": "click",
            "selector": ".myVideo",
            "request": "event",
            "vars": {
              "eventType": "click"
            }
          }
        },
        "transport": {
            "beacon": true,
            "xhrpost": true
        }
      }
    </script>
  </amp-analytics>
```

`

Comment: Not sure about this but have you tried using [AMP-bind](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=ampbind+amphtml&oq=ampbind+amphtml&aqs=chrome..69i57.3466j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Seems that's closest method to what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [amp-analytics variables docs](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/analytics-vars.md#variables-as-data-attribute) and I believe only `click` and `visible` events are able to consume `data-vars-*` attributes at this time.

> ### Variables as data attribute
>
> ---
>
> For the following event types, variables can be passed as part of the element level data attribute
>
> - visible
> - click

Feel free [to open a feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new) at the AMP Project GitHub for data var substitution for analytics events other than `click` and `visible`. Another approach could be a feature request for the video id as a standard video analytics variable, since almost all videos have an ID, which could at least be the URL.

As a workaround for now you could create a separate video analytics trigger for each video id on the page and manually specify the id in the `vars` block.

Comment: Yes, that what I suspected, Thanks.
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/14638